# how to get text from image logo on Login page using Selenium Webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**HTML Code below:**

```
<a href="http://mysite.com.au" target="_blank"><img src="/Images/mysite-logo.png" alt="my site"></a>
<img src="/Images/my-site.png" alt="My Site Text">
```

I tried following to get the text from 'alt' attribute in image:

**1st Approach:->**

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//img[@alt='My Site Text']")
 WebElement loginpage_title;
 System.out.println("Title of Login Page is" + loginpage_title.getText());
```

**2nd Approach:->**

```
@FindBy(tagName="img")
 WebElement loginpage_logo;
 String loginpage_title=loginpage_logo.getAttribute("alt");
 System.out.println("Title of Login Page is" + loginpage_title);
```

None of the above mentioned approach is working for me.

Please provide the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: It is an image, what is the value of the `Mona Lisa`?

Comment: there is no value.this is the html code and I want to extract value from alt.

Comment: As per your first aproach, you already know the alt text, then why are you trying to find it

Comment: Also, in your first approach, you should use : .getAttribute("alt") and in second approach, it may be the case, that more the one images are there and which is causing the issue

Comment: I want to find out text value which is in alt attribute because as per my testcase I have to compare login page title to expected title. But the above mentioned both approaches not working and I get blank value. My question is how can I get text value 'My Site Text' because only value is displaying in 'alt' attribute which I have to extract and compare.

Comment: @Samy Have you tried what I shared in my second comment

Comment: @Aman --Thanks so much...getAttribute("alt") - actually worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, it should be one of these approach:

**1st Approach:->**

In first approach, the change is to use `getAttribute` function to get value of `alt` `attribute`.

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//img[@alt='My Site Text']")
 WebElement loginpage_title;
 System.out.println("Title of Login Page is" + 
       loginpage_title.getAttribute("alt") );
```

**2nd Approach:->**

In second approach, the change is to use `@FindAllBy` instead of `@FindBy`

```
@FindAllBy(tagName="img")
 List<WebElement> webelements;
 WebElement loginpage_logo = webelements.get(1); //need to be chaned according to the html
 String loginpage_title=loginpage_logo.getAttribute("alt");
 System.out.println("Title of Login Page is" + loginpage_title);
```